# propertyDataSource not updated on TextChangeEvent, should it?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

One can set the `propertyDataSource` property for a `TextArea` instance. This causes the property to be updated when the `TextArea` looses focus.

Now when using this:

```
        textArea.setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.TIMEOUT);
        textArea.setTextChangeTimeout(500);
```

... the property bound by setting the `TextArea.propertyDataSource` is not updated before notifying TextChangeListeners - only when it looses focus. Should it - is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's working as intended. Only a `ValueChangeEvent` from a `TextFields` is updating its datasource.